# What are some cultures, both modern and historic, that required vegetarianism?

Tags: history

Vegetarianism has a number of precedents throughout history and I'm wondering how many different regions of the world and cultural traditions incorporated it.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but too broad. Please, narrow it , so it can be answered. One could write a book as answer for this topic.